# excel linking cells and format changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to link the dates(in this format: **mm/dd/yy**) listed in cell in column 1 in sheet 1 to column 3 in sheet 2(in this format:**yyyy**). Ive done that with the simple link: **='Unapplied Report'!E50** , and then I did a format cell to just display the year(**yyyy**). It worked well and I applied the link down to the whole column. However, when there is a blank cell in column 1 from sheet 1 for some reason instead of linking the blank cell to column 3 in sheet 2, it displays year **1900**. What method would be best to make it show the blank cell it is supposed to show? Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your help guys, just one last question.
How would I apply the **IF(ISBLANK** formula to this **=CONCATENATE(TEXT('Unapplied Report'!A3,"0000"),TEXT('Unapplied Report'!C3,"000"),TEXT('Unapplied Report'!D3,"0000"))** without bringing up any errors?
Thanks again in advance for your help.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks for your help guys, just one last question. How would I apply the IF(ISBLANK formula to this =CONCATENATE(TEXT('Unapplied Report'!A3,"0000"),TEXT('Unapplied Report'!C3,"000"),TEXT('Unapplied Report'!D3,"0000")) without bringing up any errors? Thanks again in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('Unapplied Report'!E50),"",'Unapplied Report'!E50)
```

This checks if the original cell is blank and returns blank if it is, returning the original cell otherwise.

What was happening before is your `='Unapplied Report'!E50` formula was returning '0' when the referenced cell was blank, which is the equivalent of **00/01/1900** when converted to a date.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(ISBLANK('Unapplied Report'!E50),"",'Unapplied Report'!E50)
```